# Excel 2007 - Find a word

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have like 3000 works in an excel cell that I need to search one word in. It does not highlight the word, it only places me into the cell with the word.

Anybody has any idea how I can get the word highlighted that I am looking for?

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the font/highlighting/background of the characters you find using the Characters property in VBA. This can be packaged with the actual search or you can perform the search manually and the highlighting with a macro. See this link for code samples http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66197

Note that since you are actually changing font in Excel you will need to revert it to normal if you don't want the highlight saved with the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the whole book as an HTML. Then open it in your preferred browser, you can search in the normal way and it should highlight the desired word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting to highlight the entire cell that contains the search criteria, but I think you want only the specific text to be identified?

I haven't tried this, but here is a discussion on this:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=397445

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one long cell, or if all the long cells are in a column, you could try using the "Text to Columns" feature (under the Data tab of the Ribbon). If you set it to be delimited by space (assuming your words are separated by spaces), this will make it so that each word occupies its own cell. Then when you use Find, it will highlight the exact cell.

Another option would be to copy the range you want to search and paste into MS Word. From there, you can search, and it will highlight the exact word.

Answer (score 0):

export as a .csv then, then import so that it breaks each column on the space, then you can do what i said above, and then combine the cells.  why don't you just copy paste the contents of the cell into notepad and do a seach & replace there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to the highlighting feature in Word in Excel.

What I would suggest is doing a Replace where you set the replace with to the word you are searching for, plus set the Format (using the Format... button on the Replace tab) to a yellow color (on the Fill tab of the Replace Format dialog). Once you have that, clicking on "Replace All" will get the effect that you are seeking (that is, all instances of the term "yellow" in the worksheet will now have a yellow fill color in the cell).

I hope this is what you were thinking of.

Mike

Answer (score -1):

alt-e-f (find), type the word, then you can go thru the cells with em

Comment: It is NOT highlighting the search word, it just places me in the cell where the word is in. This is not usable.